# What are ECT parameters?

Tags: brain, neurology, electrical-stimulation, psychiatry

ECT or shock treatment is used to treat psychological disorders. How much voltage,  current and duration is used for this? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroconvulsive_therapy) mentions a treatment of 0.8 Ampere for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

[Peterchev *et al*. (2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2933093/) reports

> The current amplitude is [... ] held fixed at the device maximum (e.g., 800 mA or 900 mA)...

and that

> [constant-voltage devices are] now obsolete

The total stimulus duration as I understand is a pulse train of a few seconds [(Peterchev, 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2933093/). The duration of total treatment is about 20 minutes in the treatment room and up to an hour including recovery (source: H[opkins Hospital](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/psychiatry/specialty_areas/brain_stimulation/ect/faq_ect.html)).

Note that the total stimulus duration depends on the total amount of injected charge. This in turn depends on stimulus frequency, stimulus shape, frequency and so forth (Fig. 1). For an excellent overview see [(Peterchev *et al*., 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2933093/).

[image: stimulus shape]
<sup>Fig. 1. Sample ECT waveforms: (a) sine wave, (b) biphasic pulses with indicated parameter definitions, and (c) monophasic pulses [(Peterchev *et al*., 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2933093/)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Peterchev *et al*., *J ECT* (2010); **26**(3): 159–74](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Sk0.jpg)</sub>